# rdlc table header set problem?

Tags: rdlc

I want my rdlc report show this bellow formate ....Help me to get it

```
**Div    Dis     Thana

Name  ID  Address** 
sam   1    dssa
jame  2    dssa
s     3    dsssa
```

**name, id and address** are the table header. i want to set div,dis,thana, name top of the header and want to set group .....i want my report page break after each district ....how can i set the group on my table header......suppose

> 

```
 Div   Dis   Thana
>     Name   ID    Address
```

**report is:**

```
D    A   B
Sam   1      dssa
```

**pagebreake**

```
B    C   F
jame 2   dssw
```

Help me to set the group on table header....or show me any path to solve the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Div, Dis, and Thana are, but I think this is what you're looking for.

---

First, you need to set up two groups: one outer group for Div and Dis that has a page break after each group; one inner group for Thana for each Div and Dis group. Also, you want a group header row that includes both groups.

If you haven't set up grouping on your table already, you can follow this exactly:

1. Select the table, right-click, and go to properties.
2. On the Groups tab, either select the existing tab (`table1_Group1`?) or create a new group.
3. Enter group on fields (Div and Dis), one per line.
4. Check *Page break at end* to break after each Dis.
5. Click OK.

Then set up a second group. This is the inner Thana group:

1. Add a new group.
2. Enter group on field Thana.
3. Check *Include group header*. This inner header is the one you want, grouped by Div, Dis and then Thana.
4. OK out.

You should now have the groups set up and see a new row in your table. This is the group header row for the second group (shown by "(<sub>2</sub>"). Set expressions in each textbox for the group header for Div, Dis, and Thana.

Then in the details row, set the expressions for Name, ID, and address.

*Note: depending on the number of columns and layout of your table, you may need to experiment with merging columns, border styles/colors, and textboxes. This is a finicky art but eventually you will get the hang of it.*

Comment: How to set the document map on group_1 .in document map how to set div and dis value separately.

Comment: You can't set div and dis separately as the document map is only one string. You can, however, have three groups instead (div, dis, and then thana) and the document maps will nest themselves properly.

Comment: i already do it ....thanks .....after create three group i get some extra space how to remove those extra space ....tell me about the parent group field of edit group tab

Comment: What kind of extra space? Where?

Comment: after add three groups .....there are some space between rows ....i want to show them together how to remove the space

Comment: As for the parent field, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251700(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Not sure about the spaces - are they extra group headers or something? Extra rows?

Comment: That is group footers Right Click Go to Properties make those rows visibility option as False.

Answer (score 0):

That is group footers 
Right Click Go to Properties
make those rows `visibility` option  as `False`.